# Django proxy model breaks related name queries

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Why would a Django proxy model break a query using a related name?

I have some models like:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='tags')
```

I wanted to expose a filtered view for Category, that defined a very specific query subset, so I created a proxy:

```
class CategoryProxy(Category):
    class Meta:
         proxy=True
```

However, now any query that references "tags" throws the error:

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'tags' into field. Choices are: ...
```

If I comment out the proxy, the error goes away. Why is this?

Comment: shouldn't it be `class CategoryProxy(Category)`? you need to show a bit more of your code and a full error traceback to have enough info to help

Comment: That was a typo in my example. That's not the problem in my code though.

Comment: no, but you need to show more code and error traceback for anyone to be able to help you

Comment: I get the same problem, have you resolve it?